# Published swf different from fla timeline preview

Tags: flash, export, publish

I try to modify an existing .fla file, created in flash CS4 or CS5. My goal is to translate some of the text. I open the file in flash CS5.5 without problems. I can change the text as well by modifying it directly in the layers or by modifying it in the library movies.

When I run the animation by clicking the "play" button in the timeline, it looks exactly as I want it. When I try to export or publish the file to an SWF, about half of the translations are still the original words.

In publish settings, I removed the "include hidden layers" option, so that shouldn't be an issue.

I have almost no previous flash experience. It's driving me crazy...

Thank you for any hints !

Comment: Is the text static or dynamic, classic or Text Layout Framework?

Comment: From what I googled, it looks to be "classic text". I can't find the text in the actionscript, so I'm guessing it's static text.

Comment: Also: the movie was designed to play in flash player 8, actionscript 2. It has no external XML files as far as I can tell.

Comment: If you click on the text object, you should be able to see if it is static or dynamic in the object properties panel.

Answer (score 0):

For other people with the same problem: although the text was marked as "static", it was somehow changed by some actionscript code. I deleted almost all actionscript code (which I didn't need anyway), and that solved the problem.